# update time to date-time column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I were forget to change **Time Zone in my PHP code**, now database have saved the time of London time zone. So I want to update my column;s time only(not date). I have column of dateTime in mysql. I only want to add 5 hour in the time.
how it is possible. I tried below SQL but its not working:

```
update 
tblswitchemprequest
set time(responseDateTime)+5
```

Comment: [DATEADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATE_ADD` which requires two parameters, first is the initial datetime and second paramter comprises of the keyword `INTERVAL`, the quantity to be added and the unit of quantity to be added.

In your case the source time would be `responseDateTime` and second parameter would be `INTERVAL 5 HOUR`. It returns the updated datetime

```
UPDATE tblswitchemprequest SET responseDateTime = DATE_ADD(responseDateTime, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Comment: UPDATE tblswitchemprequest
SET responseDateTime = responseDateTime + INTERVAL 5 Hour

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
DATEADD(hh, 5, responseDateTime)
```

Your query should look like

```
update tblswitchemprequest set responseDateTime = DATEADD(hh, 5, responseDateTime)
```

Comment: FUNCTION ttl_employee_switch.DATEADD does not exist